# Simple question about conditional probability of joint distributions

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, bernoulli-distribution

I have this maths problem that I'm trying to figure out. It looks really simple but it confuses the heck out of me.

**The question:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables so that $X \sim Bernoulli(1/2)$ and $Y \sim Bernoulli(1/4)$. Find $P(X=1 | X=1 \text{ or } Y=1)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, does it really matter what $Y$ is?? I have a formula for calculating conditional probability of joint distributions involving two discrete random variables, but I don't understand how to apply it in this case. Or if it should even be applied in this case. I think it's the "or" that trips me up.

Comment: Since the answer is not simply $P(X=1 \mid X=1)=1$, then yes it does matter.  There are jointly four possible outcomes for $X$ and $Y$.  You can work out the probability of each and of the event $X=1 \text{ or } Y=1$ and then find the conditional probability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X=1|X=1 \,\,\text  {OR} \,\,Y=1)= P(X=1|(X=1)\cup (Y=1))$$ $$=\frac {P(X=1)} {P(X=1)\cup (Y=1)}=\frac {P(X=1)} {P(X=1)+P(Y=1)-P(X=1, Y=1)}$$ $$=\frac {P(X=1)} {P(X=1)+P(Y=1)-P(X=1) P(Y=1)}.$$

I have use the following facts:

$A \cap (A\cup B)=A$

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: An alternative is $\dfrac{P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0)}{P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)}$